# how to run a iteration when exceptions occurs also

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I have a hash map and some of the values are null in the hash map.So I wanted to print only the key and value pairs from the hash map.So I am trying with

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Long>> map=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Long>>();
try{
    for(int s=0;s<map.size();s++){

       // checking for null
       if(map.get(s).size()>0 || map.get(s)!=null){

            System.out.println(s+" is the key and "+map.get(s).size() +" is the size of values for the key and "+map.get(s).toString()+ " are the values");

                                                  }
                                  }
    } 
    catch(Exception e){
    }
```

But this runs when the the value for the first element is not null and stops whenever it is null in this case.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about... checking for null before calling size() and toString() on the value? Why do you throw an exception? Why do you use a map to store keys from 0 to N, rather than just a list? And of course, why don't you indent your code properly to make it readable?

Comment: And it's still not indented properly, and you're not answering any of my questions.

Comment: checking for null before calling size() and toString() on the value?--done in if statement check,  throw an exception?--removed, Why do you use a map to store keys from 0 to N, rather than just a list-- I need a map in this case to search very fast for given key.

Comment: No, not done. An ArrayList is faster at getting an element by index than a map. Make your code correct. Think about speed if you have a speed problem. And you should never, ever, cacth NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checking for null` is wrong. As you access size() of a possibly null value before you check if it null.

Change your expression `map.get(s).size()>0 || map.get(s)!=null` to `map.get(s) != null && map.get(s).size() > 0` if you want to print only values with size > 0 or simply use `if (map.get(s) != null)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map.Entry;
  HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Long>> map=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Long>>   
  ();
     ArrayList<Long> s = new ArrayList<>(); 
     s.add(1L);
     s.add(2L);
     map.put(0, s);
     map.put(1, s);
     map.put(null, null);
     map.put(1, s);
     for(Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Long>> kv:map.entrySet()){
         System.out.println(kv.getValue()+","+kv.getKey());;
     }
```

hope it works!